# MissingTranslation for default language ( "..." is not translated in "en")

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, lint

I want to generate a signed apk and get following error:

```
Error:(65) Error: "..." is not translated in "en" (English) [MissingTranslation]
```

My projects ONLY contain default folders (no addon for an language) like `values` folder for example and ONE language, which is german (meaning, I have an `values-de` folder)

My default language is english, so all resources that do not belong to a special language should be the english ones.

**QUESTIONS**

*Why is android studio telling me, it's missing the `en` language, although I don't have a single en-folder? Maybe an en-folder is part of a gradle import? Can I somehow exclude them? Actually, I don't know where the `en` comes from as I don't use it anywhere...*

**EXAMPLE**

I only have `values` and `values-de`folder!

In `values` I have following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="pause_alarms">
        <item>Silent</item>
        <item>Vibrate</item>
        <item>Sound</item>
        <item>Vibrate + Sound</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

In `values-de` I have following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="pause_alarms">
        <item>Leise</item>
        <item>Vibrieren</item>
        <item>Ton</item>
        <item>Vibrieren + Ton</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: I do so. I get this error for all array entries which are translatable AND are translated to german... And there english values are in the `values/arrays.xml` file and their german values are in `values-de/arrays.xml`...

Comment: actually, I added an example... And I get thsi error for ALL translatable values in my `arrays.xml`... And how should android studio know, that my default language is `en`? Actually, it does not know that, not on purpose. I don't define the locale of my default resources...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know where the `en` comes from, but if I define the language of my default resources in the xml file like following

```
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:locale="en">
```

the error disappears...

Probably, I just guess, some gradle imports have the `en` folder...

Comment: It has been long time since then, but the error keeps showing even if I add `tools:locale="en"`. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the build is getting confused by the string-array? It's good practice to have the array only in one values folder and define the strings as external resources. So instead of your entry, it's better to do this:

```
<string-array name="pause_alarms">
    <item>@string/silent</item>
    <item>@string/vibrate</item>
    ... etc ...
</string-array>
```

Then in res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="silent">Silent</string>
<string name="vibrate">Vibrate</string>
 ... etc ...
```

and in res/values-de/strings.xml

```
<string name="silent">Leise</string>
<string name="vibrate">Vibrieren</string>
 ... etc ...
```

This way you don't have to keep 2 string-arrays up to date and sync'd in order, just the raw string values.

The "en" thing is weird - in the docs for localization, Google never mention English. They only ever talk about the "default" language. Makes sense, as values is language-neutral. You could write the default in Spanish and have a values-en folder, it wouldn't matter.

Other things to check - are you using local libraries in the project folder? Maybe they have resources in a values-en folder that are getting picked up and confusing the build system?

Comment: actually, it's a good advice... but I've found the solution... I don't know where the `en`comes from, but if I define the language of my default resources in the xml file (like `<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="en">`, the error disappears... thanks for the tipp though

Comment: PS: I use local libraries, but I checked all of them, I never used other languages yet... But I didn't check the gradle imports...

Comment: Nice, maybe post that as the solution and auto-answer in case someone else comes across this problem. How the heck did you come up with that solution? :)

Comment: I will post it... There were some posts on google forum which let me believe that this could work...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was due to the existence of a folder named values-en that was missing some files that were present in the other folders.

Comment: same for me. Some module contains empty **values-en** folder which caused this warnings/errors. Thanks a lot for hint :)